# Is it possible in VScode to diff two selections, two sections, two functions, etc of the same file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, diff

My usecase is to make an abstraction of two functions that are in the same file and are quite similar.

I want to diff these two functions to make sure I don't miss any details where they differ.

But I'm sure there are many other usecases. Two paragraphs in a single text document, etc...

I can't seem to find a way to do this in VScode, or indeed anybody asking about it.

Is this possible and I just don't know it?

Failing that, is there a nice little trick to achieve it without specific support for it?

Comment: Can you try explaining that again? Nothing you are saying is making sense. What coding language?  Or does it matter?

Comment: @selbie Any language, any text can be diffed. In my case I was generalizing a TypeScript function.

Comment: I tried to explain it better. If it still doesn't make sense to you can you go into detail about what part you don't understand and I'll try again.

Comment: create 2 txt files (or language files), copy the function content to them and compare them. If you don't need to do this 10 times a day no need for an extension or feature

Answer (score 1):

> Failing that, is there a nice little trick to achieve it without specific support for it?

Yes. Copy the sections into each their own text file, and then compare those two files. You can select them in the Explorer and use the "Compare Selected" context menu action, or individually select using "Select for Compare". Or via commandline with `code -diff <file> <file>`.

Comment: Exactly what I usually do, just wasn't sure there wasn't more direct support.